# haskell fold rose tree paths

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

let us say we have a tree...

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
```

and that tree has some nodes

```
t = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 []], Node 4 [], Node 5 [Node 6 []]]
```

the following function will `collect` the paths in a tree.

```
paths :: Tree a -> [[a]]
paths (Node n []) = [[n]]
paths (Node n ns) = map ((:) n . concat . paths) ns
```

like so:

```
*Main> paths t
[[1,2,3],[1,4],[1,5,6]]
```

But now how could we `fold` these paths? Obviously we could do this. Which folds after finding the paths.

```
wastefullFold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> [b]
wastefullFold f z (Node n ns) = map (foldr f z) $ paths (Node n ns)

*main> wastefullFold (+) 0 t
[6,5,12]
```

The closest I can some is:

```
foldTreePaths :: (a -> [b] -> [b]) -> [b] -> Tree a -> [[b]]
foldTreePaths f z (Node n []) = [f n z]
foldTreePaths f z (Node n ns) = map (f n . concat . foldTreePaths f z) ns

*Main> foldTreePaths (:) [] a
[1,2,3],[1,4],[1,5,6]]

*Main> foldTreePaths ((:) . (+ 1)) [] a
[[2,3,4],[2,5],[2,6,7]]
```

but I feel like there should be something cleaner than this below

```
*Main> foldTreePaths (\node base -> [node + sum base]) [0] a
[[6],[5],[12]]
```

Basically I do not know how to write `foldTreePaths` with the following signature:

`foldTreePaths :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> [b]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is pretty easy with comprehensions:

```
foldRose f z (Node x []) = [f x z]
foldRose f z (Node x ns) = [f x y | n <- ns, y <- foldRose f z n]

> foldRose (:) [] t
[[1,2,3],[1,4],[1,5,6]]
> foldRose (+) 0 t
[6,5,12]
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't think that you could write comprehensions like this. big + 1