# Lazy Folding of Infinite Depth & Infinite Breadth Rose Tree to its Edge Paths

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tree, lazy-evaluation, fold

This question [haskell fold rose tree paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032137/haskell-fold-rose-tree-paths) delved into the code for folding a rose tree to its paths. I was experimenting with infinite rose trees, and I found that the provided solution was not lazy enough to work on infinite rose trees with infinity in both depth and breadth.

Consider a rose tree like:

```
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a] deriving (Show, Functor)
```

Here's a finite rose tree:

```
finiteTree = Rose "root" [ 
    Rose "a" [ 
        Rose "d" [], 
        Rose "e" []
    ], 
    Rose "b" [ 
        Rose "f" [] 
    ], 
    Rose "c" [] 
]
```

The output of the edge path list should be:

```
[["root","a","d"],["root","a","e"],["root","b","f"],["root","c"]]
```

Here is an infinite Rose tree in both dimensions:

```
infiniteRoseTree :: [[a]] -> Rose a
infiniteRoseTree ((root:_):breadthGens) = Rose root (infiniteRoseForest breadthGens)

infiniteRoseForest :: [[a]] -> [Rose a]
infiniteRoseForest (breadthGen:breadthGens) = [ Rose x (infiniteRoseForest breadthGens) | x <- breadthGen ]

infiniteTree = infiniteRoseTree depthIndexedBreadths where
    depthIndexedBreadths = iterate (map (+1)) [0..]
```

The tree looks like this (it's just an excerpt, there's infinite depth and infinite breadth):

```
      0
      |
      |
    [1,2..]
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
[2,3..]  [2,3..]
```

The paths would look like:

```
[[0,1,2..]..[0,2,2..]..]
```

Here was my latest attempt (doing it on GHCi causes an infinite loop, no streaming output):

```
rosePathsLazy (Rose x []) = [[x]]
rosePathsLazy (Rose x children) = 
    concat [ map (x:) (rosePathsLazy child) | child <- children ]

rosePathsLazy infiniteTree
```

The provided solution in the other answer also did not produce any output:

```
foldRose f z (Rose x []) = [f x z]
foldRose f z (Rose x ns) = [f x y | n <- ns, y <- foldRose f z n]

foldRose (:) [] infiniteTree
```

Both of the above work for the finite rose tree.

I tried a number of variations, but I can't figure out to make the edge folding operation lazy for infinite 2-dimensional rose tree. I feel like it has something to do with infinite amounts of `concat`.

Since the output is a 2 dimensional list. I can run a 2 dimensional `take` and project with a depth-limit or a breadth-limit or both at the same time!

Any help is appreciated!

---

After reviewing the answers here and thinking about it a bit more. I came to the realisation that this is unfoldable, because the resulting list is *uncountably* infinite. This is because an infinite depth & breadth rose tree is not a 2 dimensional data structure, but an infinite dimensional data structure. Each depth level confers an extra dimension. In other words, it is somewhat equivalent to an infinite dimensional matrix, imagine a matrix where each field is another matrix.. ad-infinitum. The cardinality of the infinite matrix is `infinity ^ infinity`, which has been proven (I think) to be uncountably infinite. This means any infinite dimensional data structure is not really computable in a useful sense.

To apply this to the rose tree, if we have infinite depth, then the paths never enumerate past the far left of the rose tree. That is this tree:

```
      0
      |
      |
    [1,2..]
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
[2,3..]  [2,3..]
```

Would produce a path like: `[[0,1,2..], [0,1,2..], [0,1,2..]..]`, and we'd never get past `[0,1,2..]`.

Or in another way, if we have a list containing lists ad-infinitum. We can also never count (enumerate) it either, as there would be an infinite amount of dimensions that the code would jump to.

This also has some relationship to real numbers being uncountably infinite too. In a lazy list of infinite real numbers would just infinitely produce `0.000..` and never enumerate past that.

I'm not sure how to formalise the above explanation, but that's my intuition. (For reference see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) It'd be cool to see someone expand on applying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument to this problem.

This book seems to expand on it: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=OPFoJZeI8MEC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=haskell+uncountably+infinite&source=bl&ots=Z5hM-mFT6A&sig=ovzWV3AEO16M4scVPCDD-gyFgII&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=haskell%20uncountably%20infinite&f=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but you might be interested in this detailed answer on how Haskell's `permutations` function is written so that it works on infinite lists:

[What does this list permutations implementation in Haskell exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484348/what-does-this-list-permutations-implementation-in-haskell-exactly-do/24564307#24564307)

**Update**

Here's a simpler way to create an infinite Rose tree:

```
iRose x = Rose x [ iRose (x+i) | i <- [1..] ]

rindex (Rose a rs) [] = a
rindex (Rose _ rs) (x:xs) = rindex (rs !! x) xs
```

Examples:

```
rindex (iRose 0) [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]     -- returns: 26
rindex infiniteTree [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]  -- returns: 13
```

**Infinite Depth**

If a Rose tree has infinite depth and non-trivial width (> 1) there can't be an algorithm to list all of the paths just using a counting argument - the number of total paths is uncountable.

**Finite Depth & Infinite Breadth**

If the Rose tree has finite depth the number of paths is countable even if the trees have infinite breadth, and there is an algorithm which can produce all possible paths. Watch this space for updates.

Comment: I'll note that you *can* fold an infinite depth and infinite width tree if you let the result be a function similar to `rindex`, except with infinite index list.

Comment: How do you define depth? The supremum of the length of all paths? If all paths are finite (but maybe with unbounded length), then the number of paths is countable (as long the breadth at each node is countable).

Comment: You can't list *all* paths. But you can have a single list of paths with a remarkable property: given any finite prefix of a path's indices, there is a finite index in the list of paths containing a path with an identical prefix. That's almost certainly good enough for computing, since vanishingly few infinite paths are representable in finite space anyway. See @dfeuer's answer for how to do it.

Comment: @DanielWagner: You can list all paths as long each path has finite length, but you have to change their order.

Comment: I added my intuition for why this tree is unfoldable.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, dfeuer has deleted his answer, which included a very nice insight and only a minor, easily-fixed problem. Below I discuss his nice insight, and fix the easily-fixed problem.

His insight is that the reason the original code hangs is because it is not obvious to `concat` that any of the elements of its argument list are non-empty. Since we can prove this (outside of Haskell, with paper and pencil), we can cheat just a little bit to convince the compiler that it's so.

Unfortunately, `concat` isn't quite good enough: if you give `concat` a list like `[[1..], foo]`, it will never draw elements from `foo`. The [`universe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) collection of packages can help here with its [`diagonal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:diagonal) function, which does draw elements from all sublists.

Together, these two insights lead to the following code:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Universe.Helpers

paths (Node x []) = [[x]]
paths (Node x children) = map (x:) (p:ps) where
    p:ps = diagonal (map paths children)
```

If we define a particular infinite tree:

```
infTree x = Node x [infTree (x+i) | i <- [1..]]
```

We can look at how it behaves in ghci:

```
> let v = paths (infTree 0)
> take 5 (head v)
[0,1,2,3,4]
> take 5 (map head v)
[0,0,0,0,0]
```

Looks pretty good! Of course, as observed by ErikR, we cannot have all paths in here. However, given any finite prefix `p` of an infinite path through `t`, there is a finite index in `paths t` whose element starts with prefix `p`.

Comment: I deleted my post because user3237465 pointed out that it too gets stuck. I couldn't quite figure out why, and couldn't come up with a quick fix.

Comment: The part of my post I like best is the infinite tree construction. You might consider stealing it.

Comment: @dfeuer, I wasn't first: someone else said that the version with `concatMap` loops. The problem was with `concatMap`: `map paths` results in `[(x1 : th1), (x2 : th2),...]`, `concat` then yields only the first `x1`. If we replace `concat` with `shift xs = map head xs ++ concat (map tail xs)`, then `paths` does produce some non-interesting input. I guess `diagonal` works because paths are forced more deeply: e.g. if the depth of a `Rose` more than `2`, then we know that all paths have at least `2` elements.

Comment: @user3237465, the part I don't understand yet is why `th1 = _|_`.

Comment: *"non-interesting output" instead of "non-interesting input". @dfeuer, [looks](http://lpaste.net/143037) like because in `a:as` `as` just never gets forced. But I don't understand how `diagonal` is different, and don't want to trace it manually.

Comment: @dfeuer Oh, how nasty! I hadn't even tried to run your code, so that problem completely escaped my notice.

Comment: I added my intuition for why this tree is unfoldable.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

ErikR has explained why you can't produce a list that necessarily contains all the paths, but it is possible to list paths lazily from the left. The simplest trick, albeit a dirty one, is to recognize that the result is never empty and force that fact on Haskell.

```
paths (Rose x []) = [[x]]
paths (Rose x children) = map (x :) (a : as)
  where
    a : as = concatMap paths children
    -- Note that we know here that children is non-empty, and therefore
    -- the result will not be empty.
```

For making very infinite rose trees, consider

```
infTree labels = Rose labels (infForest labels)
infForest labels = [Rose labels' (infForest labels')
                      | labels' <- map (: labels) [0..]]
```

As chi [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128736/haskell-lazy-folding-of-infinite-depth-infinite-breadth-rose-tree-to-its-edge#comment54078019_33130939), while this definition of `paths` is productive, it will in some cases repeat the leftmost path forever, and never reach any more. Oops! So some attempt at fairness or diagonal traversal is *necessary* to give interesting/useful results.

Comment: Great answer! Although you must replace `concat` with [`diagonal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:diagonal) or similar. Otherwise, since the first child will produce infinitely many paths, `concatMap paths children` will not contain any path from the second child at any finite index. So the recursive call should be `diagonal (map paths children)` instead.

Comment: Can you write `infTree` in terms of the `Rose` constructor? It would make it easier to test. I'm getting a hang on: `head ((paths (iRose 0)) !! 2)`.  My code: http://lpaste.net/143025

Comment: I guess I should expect a hang for just the `concatMap` version. However, I'm still getting a hang with the diagonals version - which might mean I've implemented `diags` incorrectly.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I explicitly did not attempt, in this implementation, to reach any particularly interesting set of paths; I was just trying to show where the original code got stuck and to attempt to patch that up.

Comment: @ErikR Your `paths2` makes its recursive call to `paths` instead of `paths2`.

Comment: I figured out my problem with the `paths2` function. see this paste: http://lpaste.net/143025

Comment: @ErikR There seems to be some problem with your `diags`, as well: I can confirm that replacing `diags` with `diagonal` in your second paste makes `test2` stop looping. Even if you don't want to install the `universe` package, you can just copy the definition of that function from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/src/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#diagonal) -- it's only about eight lines of code.

Comment: I am puzzled by this, especially when you say "from the left". Consider a binary tree when each node has exactly two children labelled `True,False` in that order. The first path you generate is `repeat True`. OK. What is, however, the _second_ path? I fear that it is once again `repeat True`. Worse, you will never reach some different path (one with some `False` inside). The whole result is, I fear, `repeat (repeat True)`.

Comment: @chi I believe you are reiterating my comment about using `diagonal` instead of `concat`. =)

Comment: @DanielWagner Correct. But I wonder which kinds of paths are actually produced using a fair `diagonal`. Maybe only those of the form `prefix ++ repeat True` ?

Comment: @chi I expect so, yes.

Comment: @chi, interesting point! Some "fairness" seems to be necessary to make any useful results at all.

Comment: @dfeuer, does your version produce anything except for the first path? I can't make it work with, say, `infiniteTree` from the question: `take 2 $ map (take 1) $ paths infiniteTree` loops.